# SQL - Cause of aborted concurrent transactions

Tags: sql, transactions

When setting the isolation level over multiple transactions, what can be the cause for aborting a transaction?

i assume that the isolation level defines which anomalies are allowed/not allowed to happen by appropriate locking, and not by aborting the transaction - is this a correct assumption?

So far the only reason I can think of is when the execution deadlocks and one of the transactions must be aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one transaction T1 is requesting some resource R1 that is locked by another transaction T2, then T1 could time out and abort.

This is not yet a deadlock situation.  Deadlock is when both T1 and T2 get stalled, each waiting for the other to release a lock the other has on some resource.